# Dados temporais contínuos em R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico, séries-temporais

Agrupei um dataset de casos de covid-19 por óbitos mensais, mas não consigo plotar os resultados. Alguém sabe uma maneira mais elegante ou correta de se fazer isso?

Tratei a base de dados, e no final fica conforme no resumo. Fiz o agrupamento e depois o plot, mas o gráfico fica com dados faltantes, conforme mostro abaixo.

É possível plotar os dados contínuos mês a mès, acabando o ano de 2020 e continuando em 2021 sucessivamente?

**Resumo dos meus dados**

```
> glimpse(dados)
Rows: 1,984,377
Columns: 5
$ data   <date> 2020-02-25, 2020-02-26, 2020-02-27, 2020-02-...
$ obitos <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
$ semana <int> 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11...
$ mes    <ord> fev, fev, fev, fev, fev, mar, mar, mar, mar, ...
$ ano    <dbl> 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 202...
```

**Agrupamento dos dados**

```
dados_mensais <- group_by(dados, ano, mes) %>% 
  summarise(total_obitos=sum(obitos))
```

**Gráfico**

```
ggplot(dados_mensais, aes(x=mes, y=total_obitos)) +
  geom_line(lwd=1.1, col='red')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = number_format(scale = 1/100000, suffix = 'mil'))+
  labs(x='Anos', y=NULL, title='Evolução da população brasileira') +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: Gráfico faltando informações...]

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SOPT! Seria interessante você colocar uma pequena parte dos seus dados para poder reproduzir (usando `dput()` por exemplo).

Comment: E não use a *tag* rstudio se a pergunta não for específica dessa GUI.

Comment: @Artur_Indio interessante essa dica de amostra com o dput(). Já adicionei aqui no script.Segue o link para a amostra dos dados: [amostra-dados](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12GkSxfQJ9IKDpUGCMvRWYZj9gsQKpHyf/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta usei a tag porque era a IDE que estou utilizando, não me atentei para isso. Obrigado.

Comment: @jaac no caso vc deveria colocar o resultado do ´dput´ na sua pergunta, colocando por exemplo 10% dos seus dados e não o link dos dados na nuvem para alguém fazer o download.

Comment: O ficheiro do link e os dados da pergunta são suficientemente diferentes para não ser possível reproduzir o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é adicionar a variável **ano** como *facet* no gráfico:

```
   ggplot(dados_mensais, aes(x=mes, y=total_obitos)) +
      geom_line(lwd=1.1, col='red')+
      scale_y_continuous(labels = number_format(scale = 1/100000, suffix = 'mil'))+
      labs(x='Anos', y=NULL, title='Evolução da população brasileira') +
      theme_minimal()+
      facet_grid(~.ano, scales = "free", space = "free")
```